# Is there a word for the sensation of: Realizing you do not realize/know something?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word to describe the feeling of knowing that there are things you will never know/realize?

For example you could live your whole life not knowing that 2 friends you met at different times in your life are actually brothers.

Comment: There are known unknowns and unknown unknowns. There is maybe an unknowable unknown somewhere.

Comment: OP can help by showing some background research to start with. Good Luck.